# PHP change URL Parameter in a string

Tags: php, regex, post, get

Trying to change the URL parameter value of "page" to "99" in the below string.

```
$pageURL = "http://www.test.com/search?loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=45&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002"
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
preg_replace("&page=.*&", "&page=99&", $pageURL);
```

Here is the result I want. Notice the parameter is now "&page=99&" ..etc.

```
$pageURL = "http://www.test.com/search?loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=99&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002"
```

Comment: *any* page number becomes 99 ?

Comment: The parameter page will have a new value of "99" as opposed to the original "45"

Comment: if its always 45 to 99 don't use regular expressions just `str_replace` its far more efficient `str_replace("&page=45&", "&page=99&", $pageURL);`

Answer (score 3):

One option without regular expressions is to use parse_url with parse_str then put the URL back together.

```
>>> $url = parse_url("http://www.test.com/search?loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=45&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002")
=> [
   "scheme" => "http",
   "host"   => "www.test.com",
   "path"   => "/search",
   "query"  => "loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=45&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002"
   ]
>>> $query = [];
=> []
>>> parse_str($url['query'], $query)
=> null
>>> $query
=> [
   "loc"       => "Rich, VA",
   "serv"      => "1",
   "spec"      => "0",
   "min_price" => "5",
   "max_price" => "9999",
   "date"      => "",
   "time"      => "0",
   "filters"   => "0",
   "page"      => "45",
   "latPos"    => "459.16689191899521",
   "longPos"   => "-1263.08099819543457",
   "zoom"      => "11",
   "ne_lat"    => "499.31460613487112",
   "ne_lng"    => "-1222.88049770715332",
   "sw_lat"    => "458.90693340071935",
   "sw_lng"    => "-1923.2801253927002"
   ]
>>> $query['page'] = 99
=> 99
>>> $url['query'] = http_build_query($query);
=> "loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=99&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002"
>>> http_build_url($url)
```

For http_build_url you need the pecl-http extension. If you don't have it you can just concatenate.

```
>>> $url['scheme'] . '://' $url['host'] . $url ['path'] . '?' . $url['query']
=> "http://www.test.com/search?loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=99&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002"
```

Here is an example script

```
$pageURL = "http://www.test.com/search?loc=Rich%2C+VA&serv=1&spec=0&min_price=5&max_price=9999&date=&time=0&filters=0&page=45&latPos=459.16689191899521&longPos=-1263.08099819543457&zoom=11&ne_lat=499.31460613487112&ne_lng=-1222.88049770715332&sw_lat=458.90693340071935&sw_lng=-1923.2801253927002";
$newUrl = parse_url($pageUrl);
$query = parse_str($new_url['query']);
$query['page'] = 99;
$newUrl['query'] = http_build_query($query);
http_build_url($newUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost right:

```
preg_replace("/&page=\d+&/", "&page=99&", $pageURL);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you know exactly what to replace, use str_replace instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try `preg_replace("/&page=[^&]*/", "&page=99", $pageURL);`

Your search includes the & character (. is any non newline character), which is problematic.